# Estimating duplication percentage between rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, similarity

I have an Excel (2010) data file with over 200 variables (columns), and over 1,000 records (rows), each identified with a unique id number.  However, I'm suspicious that some of these records are fabricated, i.e., someone took an existing record, replicated it, and changed only a few numbers to make it a little different.  Therefore, I need to produce a matrix that will show me the number/percent of "same values" between each record and all other records (e.g., record 1 and record 2 share 75 equal values, record 1 and record 3 share 57 equal values, record 2 and record 3 share 45 equal values, etc.).  I have a few workarounds, but they take hours and don't produce a simple matrix.  I don't care about the difference between the values - just whether they are equal or not.  Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how well this will perform on a huge dataset but:

```
Sub T()

    Dim d, m(), nR As Long, nC As Long, r As Long, r2 As Long, c As Long
    Dim v1, v2, i As Long
    d = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    nR = UBound(d, 1)
    nC = UBound(d, 2)
    ReDim m(1 To nR, 1 To nR)

    For r = 1 To nR
        For r2 = r To nR
            i = 0
            For c = 1 To nC
                v1 = d(r, c): If IsError(v1) Then v1 = "Error!"
                v2 = d(r2, c): If IsError(v2) Then v2 = "Error!"
                If v1 = v2 Then i = i + 1
            Next c
            m(r2, r) = i
        Next r2
    Next r

    With Sheet2
        .Range("B2").Resize(nR, nR).Value = m
        'assuming your id's are in the first column...
        For r = 1 To nR
            .Cells(1 + r, 1) = d(r, 1)
            .Cells(r, r + 1) = d(r, 1)
        Next r
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm not very good at VBA, but based on your script I got it!!!  Here is my final script, with variables names for dummies (or else I get lost...) It works great, and really fast!  Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Sub CalculateDuplicationBetweenRecords()

    Dim myCases As Long
    Dim myVariables As Long
    Dim myCurrentCase As Long
    Dim myComparisonCase As Long
    Dim myCurrentVariable As Long
    Dim myCurrentCell As Long
    Dim myComparisonCell As Long
    Dim myCounter As Long
    
    '   Would be nice to automate number of cases and variables...
    myCases = 88
    myVariables = 81
    '   Insert case #1 id for results matrix - cosmetic...
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2).Value =     Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit dull on html and posting... not a programmer, so please take everything with forgiveness...

```
Sub CalculateDuplicationBetweenRecords()

Dim myCases As Long
Dim myVariables As Long
Dim myCurrentCase As Long
Dim myComparisonCase As Long
Dim myCurrentVariable As Long
Dim myCurrentCell As Long
Dim myComparisonCell As Long
Dim myCounter As Long

'   Would be nice to automate number of cases and variables...
myCases = 88
myVariables = 81
'   Insert case #1 id for results matrix - cosmetic...
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value

For myCurrentCase = 1 To myCases - 1
    For myComparisonCase = myCurrentCase + 1 To myCases
        myCounter = 0
        For myCurrentVariable = 1 To myVariables
            myCurrentCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(myCurrentCase, myCurrentVariable).Value: If IsError(myCurrentCell) Then myCurrentCell = "Error!"
            myComparisonCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(myComparisonCase, myCurrentVariable).Value: If IsError(myComparisonCell) Then myComparisonCell = "Error!"
            If myCurrentCell = myComparisonCell Then myCounter = myCounter + 1
        Next myCurrentVariable
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCurrentCase + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(myCurrentCase, 1).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, myComparisonCase + 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(myComparisonCase, 1).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(myCurrentCase + 1, myComparisonCase + 1).Value = myCounter
    Next myComparisonCase
Next myCurrentCase

End Sub
```